# How to display timeago in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I used timeAgo npm package to display time but it displays the wrong time. I display ENTDT(Entry date) also.

I install time ago package

```
npm install time-ago-pipe --save
```

app.module.ts

```
import {TimeAgoPipe} from 'time-ago-pipe';
```

declaration

`TimeAgoPipe`

```
 <ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let list of displayList;let i=index;" >
    <ion-item text-wrap *ngIf="list.STATUS=='ACTIVE'" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">
     <p style="font-size: 10px;margin-top:-5px;" [style.color]="list.ENTDT > list.DEADLINE_DT ? '#fece60' : '#9DA4AB'">{{list.ENTDT | timeAgo}}{{list.ENTDT}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I give the task few seconds ago but it display 16 hours ago.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

install moment js for angular 2 and above,

```
npm install --save angular2-moment
```

import modules in your **app.module.ts**,

```
import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MomentModule
  ]
})
```

and use it in your component like this,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    Last updated: {{myDate | amTimeAgo}}
  `
})
```

For more info, check this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-moment)

Comment: I install angular2-moment in my code as you describe. How can i used in html.

Comment: use it like <p>{{myDate | amTimeAgo}}</p>

Comment: I used like {{this.ENTDT | amTimeAgo}} but it gives error cannot find module moment.

Comment: did you import it in app.module.ts file like how i mentioned in my answer?

Comment: could you post some code to spot what went wrong? app.module.ts, component.ts, component.html